# Equivalent conditions for the ramification group(s) in a finite Galois extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L|K$ be a finite Galois extension and $v$ a discrete normalized valuation on $L$ such that its restriction to $K$ extends uniquely to $L$.

(1) Why is $G_1=\{\sigma\in G(L|K)\mid v(\sigma(x)-x)\ge 2\ \ \forall x\in\mathcal{O}\}$ equal to the ramification group $R(L|K)=\{\sigma\in G(L|K)\mid v\left(\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}-1\right)>0\ \ \forall x\in L^*\}$? (Here $\mathcal{O}$ is the valuation ring of $L$).

(2) Is it true that in general $G_s$ equals $\{\sigma\in G(L|K)\mid v(\sigma(\pi)-\pi)\ge s+1\}$, where $\pi$ is any element of $L^*$ such that $v(\pi)=1$? (The $G_s$'s are the higher ramification groups, that is $G_s=\{\sigma\in G(L|K)\mid v(\sigma(x)-x)\ge s+1\ \ \forall x\in\mathcal{O}\}$).

This question arises from Chapter II, $\S 10$ of Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory.

Comment: So here $K$ is not necessarily an algebraic number-field, as its characteristic might not be $0$? And notice that [here in wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse-Arf_theorem) the higher ramification groups are defined by your desired equality.

Comment: And [in the article by Zev Chonoles](http://math.uchicago.edu/~chonoles/expository-notes/ramificationgroups.pdf) these groups are also defined in this way. So I wonder what your definition is. Perhaps you could mention that in the post? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, $K$ is arbitrary (but the residue class field is assumed to have positive characteristic). I added the definition of the higher ramification groups, but note the difference with the other sets in (2)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (1): In $\S$ II.9 Neukirch shows that $R(L/K)$ is the (normal, hence unique) Sylow $p$-subgroup of the inertia group $I(L/K)$.  But (Proposition II.10.2) the quotient $G_0/G_1$ is cyclic of order prime to $p$, while for each $i \geq 1$, $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is a $p$-group.  Since $G_i = \{1\}$ for sufficiently large $i$, $G_1$ must be the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $I(L/K)$.  (Admittedly Proposition II.10.2 comes shortly *after* Neukirch asserts that "clearly" $R(L/K) = G_1$, so this argument is not what he has in mind.  But it is an argument, at least.)

For (2): no.  $L/K$ could be unramified, and then we can take $\pi \in K$, so $v(\sigma(\pi)-\pi) = v(0) = \infty \geq s+1$ holds for any $\sigma$, so the latter group is always equal to $G$, while $G_s = \{1\}$ for all $s$ in this case.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand that (2) is false.
I believed that (1) is true simply because Neukirch states that it is "clear" (sic!). However, I don't understand your counterexample. Isn't $R(L|K)=\{1\}$, as $L|K$ is tamely ramified?

Comment: @carizio: Hmm, I just checked Neukirch, and you're right, that's exactly what it says.  I must be mistaken, so I deleted that part of my answer.  I should think more about this.  All I can see now is that I was actually assuming $x \in \mathcal{O}$ rather than in $K$.

Comment: Thank you again! As my second question comes from the Proposition that you quoted, could you explain me why (for $s\ge 0$) is $G_s\cap\{\sigma\mid v(\sigma(\pi)-\pi)\ge s+2\}=G_{s+1}$? That's exactly what one needs to prove that the homomorphism of the Proposition is injective.

Comment: Ah, I worked it out by myself.. This also provides a different proof of (1). The fixed field of $G_0$ is the maximal unramified subextension $T$, so if we choose $\pi$ such that $v(\pi)=1$ we have $\mathcal{O}_L=\mathcal{O}_T[\pi]$ and consequently $G_{s+1}(L|K)=G_{s+1}(L|T)=\{\sigma\in G_0\mid v(\sigma(\pi)-\pi)\ge s+2\}$.

Comment: Nice solution.   But does $\mathcal{O}_L = \mathcal{O}_T[\pi]$ assume that $\lambda|\kappa$ is separable?